# Sendto shortcuts not working on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, shortcuts, send-to

I'm trying to customize my sendto shortcut following instructions posted on [a How-To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/).  The problem is that any shortcut I drop into the sendto folder doesn't appear as a shortcut when I right-click->sendto.

If I copy the actual application (say, Notepad) into the Sendto folder, it will appear as an option but it will not run.  If I create a shortcut by copying the actual application and pasting a shortcut, it doesn't appear.

Anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Check if the shortcuts are really there. Sometimes UAC causes the application to save the file in a Virtual store. Do a RunAs & then do the paste.

Comment: Did you try restarting explorer? (Either kill the process, or just log out)

Comment: I can see shortcuts in my sendto folder, even shortcuts from months ago when I first tried to set it up that still don't appear when I right-click the send-to menu.

Comment: @Ganesh... I'm not sure what you mean for the RunAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're playing around in the wrong folder.

Try navigating to `shell:sendto` from Run or Explorer.

> If I copy the actual application

You're not meant to copy the program. Just a shortcut.

**Edit:** According to http://windowsxp.mvps.org/sendtofix.htm, this issue could occur from

- The SendTo shell folder path being incorrectly set in the registry
- Missing 'drop handler' registry values

That site also has a fix for XP and Vista. Worth a try (backup registry first)

Comment: no dice.  Its strange, the shortcuts just don't appear in the sendto menu. *shrug*

Comment: @tbischel may I ask what shortcuts *are* visible?

Comment: The following things are available sendto shortcuts:

Compressed (Zipped) Folder,
Desktop,
Mail Recipient,
each I/O device, including hard drive, usb attachment, dvd drive, etc

Comment: @tbischel: still got the problem? tried the link?