# create a SendTo shortcut on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an item to my “Send To” context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/139968/how-to-add-an-item-to-my-send-to-context-menu)

How do I create a SendTo shortcut to a folder of my choice in Windows 7 ?

Comment: Does this solution given in this question - http://superuser.com/questions/96340/sendto-shortcuts-not-working-on-vista - work for Windows 7?

Comment: @ChrisF yep it does.